# IntelXDK api for android notification

Tags: intel-xdk

I'm trying to archive [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) in intel xdk. But I couldn't find any relevant API. Would be great if someone can point me to the correct source.

P/S: What I want to achieve is the notification (showing short message), instead of push notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This plugin will enable you to do local notifications in your application - https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications/

See the following for adding 3rd party plugins to your app - https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/adding-third-party-plugins-to-your-xdk-cordova-app